# Button onClickListener not work properly

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have created an application on android, in that the Button onClickListener not work properly.

First time I clicked on button it not works, but when I clicked second time it works.

My code is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
        View vi=convertView;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {           
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_model, null);
            vholder = new ViewHolder();

            vholder.hindi=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_hindi);
            vholder.eng=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_eng);                      

            vi.setTag(vholder);
        }
        else 
        {        
            vholder = (ViewHolder) (vi.getTag());
        }

        vholder.hindi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {               
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Story_List.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        vholder.eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Story_List.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return vi;
    } 

    static class ViewHolder 
    {   
        Button eng, hindi;
    }
```

My XML file is:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout001"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_eng"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="31px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_hindi"                    
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView12"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView12"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="ENG"
                android:clickable="true"                    
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:autoLink="all"                  
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_hindi"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="31px"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"                   
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView12"                  
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_eng"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="HINDI"
                android:clickable="true"                    
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
                android:autoLink="all"                  
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is vholder..,is it viweholderclass

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: Paste code where you have declared your button and vholder.

Comment: yes @rajshree ViewHolder is my class in CustomAdapter.

Comment: Have you tested it on real device or emulator? Code seems to be fine.

Comment: @GauravGupta I checked both emulator and tablet and also check in in Mobile.

Comment: post your custom xml file...

Comment: After removing android:focusableInTouchMode="true" line from xml file it is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

After removing android:focusableInTouchMode="true" line from xml file it is working properly.

Comment: Don't forget to add `android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` whenever you want any view click able inside listview item.

Comment: Ok sir. I remeber it. Thanking you !